# Where to config chromium options in atom editor

Tags: atom-editor

Due to an high dpi screen, I have to start atom with the following command to avoid blurred fonts:

```
atom --force-device-scale-factor=1 .
```

I can add the option to my desktop starters and I can define an alias for the shell. Out of curiosity, I'd like to add this configuration to the atom editor. As a result of some searching, I found the following [solution for electron](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-access-chrome-flags-in-electron/16470):

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch "js-flags", "--harmony_proxies"
```

It should be in some sort of init script. But where would I add a line like this in the atom editor?

Answer (score 0):

You could add it to

```
Setting -> Open Config Folder -> config.cson
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new on using the atom editor. How and in which format would I add this to the `config.cson`? According to documentation, the `appendSwitch` is a function. My guess would be `init.coffee`, but to reference electron there??